# Android: axes vectors from orientation/rotational angles?

Tags: android, vector, orientation, angle

So there's a couple methods in the Android SensorManager to get your phone's orientation:

```
float[] rotational = new float[9];
float[] orientation = new float[3];
SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotational, whatever, whatever, whatever);
SensorManager.getOrientation(rotational, orientation);
```

This gives you a rotation matrix called "rotational" and an array of 3 orientation angles called "orientation". However, I can't use the angles in my AR program - what I need is the actual vectors which represent the axes.

For example, in this image from Wikipedia:
[image: Euler Angles from Wikipedia]
I'm basically being given the α, β, and γ angles (though not exactly since I don't have an N - I'm being given the angles from each of the blue axes), and I need to find vectors which represents the X, Y, and Z axes (red in the image). Does anyone know how to do this conversion? The directions on Wikipedia are very complicated, and my attempts to follow them have not worked. Also, I think the data that Android gives you may be in a slightly different order or format than what the conversion directions on Wikipedia expect.

Or as an alternative to these conversions, does anyone know any other ways to get the X, Y, and Z axes from the camera's perspective? (Meaning, what vector is the camera looking down? And what vector does the camera consider to be "up"?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotational, null, gravityVals, geoMagVals);

// camera's x-axis
Vector u = new Vector(-rotational[1], -rotational[4], -rotational[7]); // right of phone (in landscape mode)
// camera's y-axis
Vector v = new Vector(rotational[0], rotational[3], rotational[6]); // top of phone (in landscape mode)
// camera's z-axis (negative into the scene)
Vector n = new Vector(rotational[2], rotational[5], rotational[8]); // front of phone (the screen)
// world axes (x,y,z):
// +x is East
// +y is North
// +z is sky
```

Answer (score 3):

The rotation matrix in Android provides a rotation from the body (a.k.a device) frame to the world (a.k.a. inertial) frame.  A normal back facing camera appears in landscape mode on the screen.  This is native mode for a tablet, so has the following axes in the device frame:

```
camera_x_tablet_body = (1,0,0)
camera_y_tablet_body = (0,1,0)
camera_z_tablet_body = (0,0,1)
```

On a phone, where portrait is native mode, a rotation of the device into landscape with top turned to point left is:

```
camera_x_phone_body = (0,-1,0)
camera_y_phone_body = (1,0,0)
camera_z_phone_body = (0,0,1)
```

Now applying the rotation matrix will put this in the world frame, so (for rotation matrix R[] of size 9):

```
camera_x_tablet_world = (R[0],R[3],R[6]);
camera_y_tablet_world = (R[1],R[4],R[7]);
camera_z_tablet_world = (R[2],R[5],R[8]);
```

In general, you can use SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem() which for the phone example above would be Display.getRotation()=Surface.ROTATION_90 and give the answer you provided.
But if you rotate differently (ROTATION_270 for example) it will be different.

Also, an aside: the best method to get orientation in Android is to listen for Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR events.  These are filled with the best possible orientation on most (i.e. Gingerbread or newer) platforms.  It is actually the vector part of the quaternion.  You can get the full quaternion using this (and last two lines are a way to get the RotationMatrix):

```
float vec[] = event.values.clone();
float quat[] = new float[4];
SensorManager.getQuaternionFromVector(quat, vec);
float [] RotMat = new float[9];
SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(RotMat, quat);
```

More information at: http://www.sensorplatforms.com/which-sensors-in-android-gets-direct-input-what-are-virtual-sensors

Answer (score 0):

The orientation matrix that you receive from getRotationMatrix should be based on the gravity field and the magnetic field - in other words X points East, Y - North, Z - the center of the Earth. (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html)

To the point of your question, I think the three rotation values can be used directly as a vector, but provide the values in reverse order: 
"For either Euler or Tait-Bryan angles, it is very simple to convert from an intrinsic (rotating axes) to an extrinsic (static axes) convention, and vice-versa: just swap the order of the operations. An (α, β, γ) rotation using X-Y-Z intrinsic convention is equivalent to a (γ, β, α) rotation using Z-Y-X extrinsic convention; this is true for all Euler or Tait-Bryan axis combinations."
Source [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Conversion_between_extrinsic_and_intrinsic_conventions)

I hope this helps!

Comment: But what vector would those 3 values give you?  I need 3 different vectors - the camera's forward, up, and right vectors.  The matrix returned by getRotationMatrix() has 9 values in it... but I can't figure out how to turn those into the 3 vectors I need.