# Android Get angle of device in the YZ Plane

Tags: android, sensors

I am trying to get the angle of the device in the range of [0, 2π).
Like This
[image: The angle of the device]
The Orientation Sensor is deprecated so I can't use that.
The `SensorManager.getOrientation()` gives the orientation in Eurler Angles which break if I hold the device vertical, because Eurler angles are in the range of [-π/2, π/2]. Points in the 2nd and 3rd quadrants are indistinguishable from the points in the 1st and 4th quadrants. So I don't know which side of the Y axis I am on.

[image: Euler Angles]

I am limited to use of API level 8 (Android 2.2) so I only have the accelerometer and magnetic field sensors available to use.

Comment: I dont't understand the pb with SensorManager.getOrientation()

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It might help you,,

[I hope this will solve your issue](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSensor/article.html)

http://capycoding.blogspot.in/2012/10/get-angle-from-sensor-in-android.html

[Look at this post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905000/android-axes-vectors-from-orientation-rotational-angles)

[Look at this post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454948/android-pitch-and-roll-issue)

Comment: I need the angle of the device itself so I have to use the sensors.

Comment: The first tutorial uses the orientation sensor which is depricated.  The other one uses SensorManager.getOrientation which gives Euler Angles unfortunately neither of these work.

Comment: Orientation Sensor is deprecated but works as well (or should I say as bad) as the other method which consists in computing both Accelerometer values and Magnetic Field ones. Getting original orientation is just hopeless on those devices *sigh*.